# How to use Microdata for URLs in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, microdata

I read [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Microdata) about Microdata in Joomla. However, I'm not able to produce a link with Microdata.

I want a Microdata output like:

```html
<a itemprop="url" href="http://someurl">
  <span itemprop="name">Some Url</span>
</a>
```

I want a link to an organisation from my client's website. My code is:

```php
$microdata = new JMicrodata('Organization');
<div <?php echo $microdata->displayScope();?>>
    echo $microdata->content( $this->item->url )->property( 'sameAs' )->display(); 
    // outputs <span itemprop="sameAs">www.url_of_company.com</span>
</div>
```

Both `url` and `sameAs` Schema.org properties are of type URL, as per my understanding.
I also tried to wrap it with an anchor tag but **Joomla is not producing `itemprop` along with `href` attribute in anchor tag.**

I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I analysed in `libraries/joomla/microdata/microdata.php` the method display(); 
and it doesn't exist any way to produce a `<a href="#" >` tag, only div, span and meta.

Btw there is a static method called `htmlProperty()`, with that you can add the property you need.

```php
<?php $microdata = new JMicrodata('Organization'); ?>
<div <?php echo $microdata->displayScope(); ?> >
    <a <?php echo JMicrodata::htmlProperty('url'); ?> href="http://google.com">
        <?php echo $microdata->content('Google')->property('name')->display(); ?>
    </a>
</div>
```